# Converting SQL to Linq syntax

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to convert sql statement to linq but did able to do that. My sql statement is -

```
string strSQL = string.Format("select   * from  test1({0}, {1}) order by ID ASC ", IsNotNull(CID), IsNotNull(Names));
```

Could someone help me how to convert this.

Thanks

Comment: you can also try LinqPad https://www.linqpad.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that test1 is a table of object of class Test1, and that class Test1 has nullable properties CID and Names, and an IComparable property Id (so you can order by Id).

I'm not sure if you use entity framework but apparently you'll have something to access your table of test1 objects:

```
IEnumerable<Test1> test1Objects = ...
```

using entity framework this would be something like:

```
IEnumerable<Test1> test1Objects = myDbContext.Test1s;
```

Your linq query will be:

```
IEnumerable<Test1> result = test1Objects
    .Where(test1 => test1.CID != null && test1.Names != null)
    .Orderby(test1 = test1.Id)
```

In words: *From every test1 item in the sequence of test1Objects, take only those test1 items that have a non-null value of test1.CID and a non-null value of test1.Names. Order the resulting sequence in ascending Id order*

This assumes that CID is a class. If CID is a nullable value-type like int? or DateTime?, you'd better use:

```
.Where(test1 => test1.CID.HasValue() && ...
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response, unfortunately, I am not using entity framework, I am using ado.net connectionstring.

Comment: but still, to use Linq, you need an IEnumerable of some class, with those properties. The where will look similar

Comment: Thanks, it will give me understanding

Answer (score 0):

Use Linqer for that. It is a tool for converting SQL to Linq. Not all querys can be converted, but you will find it as a powerful tool.

http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: Thanks, but there is no other way I can do this, I cannot run exe file

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com) an SQL-> LINQ converter,
or [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: Thanks, I cannot run exe file

Comment: ok then please refer this [Basic LINQ Query Operations (C#)...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx)